# Confidence intervals for Ridge regression

Tags: r, regression, glmnet

I can't do the confidence intervals in a ridge regression. I have this model.

```
model5 <- glmnet(train_x,train_y,family = "gaussian",alpha=0, lambda=0.01)
```

And when I do the prediction I use these command:

```
test_pred <- predict(model5, test_x, type = "link")
```

Someone knows how to do the confidence interval for the predictions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It turns out that `glmnet` doesn't offer standard errors (and therefore doesn't give you confidence intervals) as explained [here](http://www.stat.ufl.edu/archived/casella/Papers/BL-Final.pdf) and also addressed in this [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/penalized/vignettes/penalized.pdf) (excerpt below):

> It is a very natural question to ask for standard errors of regression
> coefficients or other estimated quantities. In principle such standard
> errors can easily be calculated, e.g. using the bootstrap.
>
> Still, this
> package deliberately does not provide them. The reason for this is
> that standard errors are not very meaningful for strongly biased
> estimates such as arise from penalized estimation methods. Penalized
> estimation is a procedure that reduces the variance of estimators by
> introducing substantial bias. The bias of each estimator is therefore a
> major component of its mean squared error, whereas its variance may
> contribute only a small part.
>
> Unfortunately, in most applications of
> penalized regression it is impossible to obtain a sufficiently precise
> estimate of the bias. Any bootstrap-based calculations can only give
> an assessment of the variance of the estimates. Reliable estimates of
> the bias are only available if reliable unbiased estimates are
> available, which is typically not the case in situations in which
> penalized estimates are used.
>
> Reporting a standard error of a
> penalized estimate therefore tells only part of the story. It can give
> a mistaken impression of great precision, completely ignoring the
> inaccuracy caused by the bias. It is certainly a mistake to make
> confidence statements that are only based on an assessment of the
> variance of the estimates, such as bootstrap-based confidence
> intervals do.
>
> Reliable confidence intervals around the penalized
> estimates can be obtained in the case of low dimensional models using
> the standard generalized linear model theory as implemented in lm, glm
> and coxph. Methods for constructing reliable confidence intervals in
> the high-dimensional situation are, to my knowledge, not available.

However, if you insist on confidence intervals, check out [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/statistics/comments/1vg8k0/standard_errors_in_glmnet/) post.

Comment: The `here` link is dead.